# Identify which process is responsible for heavy disk i/o under FreeBSD

Tags: command-line-interface, freebsd, hard-drive, top, io

I wonder how I can monitor which process takes out all my IO bandwith.
The only command i know is gstat but it shows cumulative info.
Is there any tools i can use to inspect the running processes for their io usage?
The system is FreeBSD 8.3

Thank you

Comment: May be tool "iotop" can help you.

Comment: @Vadim `iotop` doesn't exist on FreeBSD. *FreeBSD is not Linux*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use FreeBSD top to achieve this.

While running top interactively, press <kbd>m</kbd>.

According to [top man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=top&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%209.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) :

```
       m      Toggle the display between 'cpu' and 'io' modes.
```

Of course, this tip won't work under linux as [linux top and bsd top are different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_%28software%29) programs.

Answer (score 0):

`top -a -m io`

BSD's `top` command has 2 modes, `io` and `cpu`.

`-a` lists the full command line for processes.

This can also be invoked interactively by pressing `m` (and `a`) if desired.

The other native IO commands such as `iostat -w` and `systat -dipslay iostat` lack the processes unfortunately.