# Finding which process is reading from disk constantly on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, truenas, io, top

**EDIT**: This ended up being a scrub process. Run `zpool status -v` and read the scan status for your pool clearly.

I have a TrueNAS server running FreeBSD and this morning at 12 AM the disks started to be read from constantly. I thought this was some snapshot task, so I disabled my snapshots and restarted the server, but every time I restart the server it continues to read from my storage pool. I have stopped all running jails as well and the disks still show IO (the screenshots below are with jails running, but they look the same with jails stopped).

[image]

I can't figure out which process is causing this. I tried using `top -m io`, but this shows no R/W activity.

[image]

According to [this resource](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/how-can-i-know-which-process-is-writing-hard-disk-intensively.19648/), `top -m io` doesn't work on FreeBSD so I can't find out which process is reading from my disks:

> top io mode doesn't properly display stats

I have tried checking if there are any running snapshot tasks using `ps -aux | grep rsync`, but nothing shows except my grep command.

Here's some resources I've checked:

- [Identify which process is responsible for heavy disk i/o under FreeBSD](https://serverfault.com/questions/460634/identify-which-process-is-responsible-for-heavy-disk-i-o-under-freebsd) (useless, recommends `top`)
- [Determining which process is causing heavy disk I/O?](https://serverfault.com/questions/212661/determining-which-process-is-causing-heavy-disk-i-o) (useless, recommends `iotop` which is not available on FreeBSD)

Is it possible to get the top command working? I just want to know what process is reading from my disks and kill it.

Comment: Have you try with `htop`?

Comment: `htop` does not show RBYTES on FreeBSD, but this ended up being a scrub process. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Running…

```
top -a -m io
```

…should do the trick! If there’s no process associated with a heavy I/O - it’s kernel and you can’t really do anything about it. I mean no way to query.

It could be ZFS performs some integrity checks / scrubbing, so it might be a good lead. Take a look here:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36835/gammt.html

Comment: I feel so dumb now. It is the scrub process. I ran "zpool status -v" and see that for my storage pool "scrub in progress since Sun Aug 27 00:00:02 8.06T scanned...", so just have to let it finish. *facepalm*

Comment: Dude you’re OK! Take it easy and just let it go. Seriously! :)